# Why does Javascript regex method .test() convert an input value of undefined to a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

At first I was confused about a return value from the javascript `RegExp.prototype.test()` method.

Sample code

```
var reg = new RegExp(/[a-z]/)
var arr = ['test']

console.log(reg.test(arr[1]))
```

The above code will log out `true` to the console when I was expecting a `false` value.

Then I realized that `undefined` is converted to the string `"undefined"` and since the regex matches any lowercase character in the alphabet it returns true

Why does this conversion happen?

Comment: [`3. Let string be ? ToString(S).`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp.prototype.test), [`Undefined [...] Return "undefined"`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring). Generally, javascript is a language, that tries a lot of implicit conversions. Whether that's a good or bad thing is a different topic, but here, it expects a string, so it implicitly converts to string.

Comment: General JavaScript lesson: If you get types wrong don't expect sensible behavior. Function wants a string, you'd better pass a string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its not a duplicate because OP understands whats happening in the code, OP's question is _Why does this conversion happen?_

Comment: The argument of `RegExp` constructor must be a string, not a regex: `var reg = new RegExp('[a-z]')` or use : `var reg = /[a-z]/;`

Answer (score 1):

`RegExp.prototype.test()` expects a string, when you pass some value that is not a string, javascript tries to coerce that value to a string value.

> Why does this conversion happen?

Implicit conversion of one type of value into value of another type is a feature of javascript and it is known as [Type Coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). Javascript implicitly coerces values when the provided value is different than the expected value.

Examples of type coercion

```
console.log(2 > '1');       // true - '1' is coerced to 1
console.log(2 + '1');       // 21   - 2 is coerced to '2'
console.log(true > '0');    // true -  true coerced to 1 and '0' coerced to 0
console.log(false == '0');  // true - false coerced to 0 and '0' coerced to 0
```